# How can I choose number of agents from a population (Anylogic)?

Tags: anylogic, agents, population

In Anylogic, If I have a 6000 agents in X population..How can I choose 2000 form this population to do a specific task ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok that you always select the same 2000 agents then this would work:

```
int i=0;
ArrayList<Agent> subsetOfAgents = new ArrayList<Agent>(2000);
for(Agent a : population)
{
   if(i >= 2000) break;
   subsetOfAgents.add(a);
   i++;
}
```

Your 2000 agents are then available in subsetOfAgents.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But actually I don't need to add the same 2000 agents. I have a state chart and in every state I need to add agents based on specific criteria..@T_D

Comment: Then check for the criteria in the loop like: if(a.criteria > 5) subsetOfAgents.add(a)